Issues deploying java application google cloud app engine flex environment
I am trying to deploy java application to google app engine flex environment. I am using runtime_config as jdk: java11. Following is the app.yaml file:
runtime: java
env: flex

runtime_config:  
  jdk: openjdk11


handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
  secure: always

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 2
  cool_down_period_sec: 120
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.6

endpoints_api_service:
  name: my-project-2-0-dev.appspot.com
  config_id: 2023-08-16r1

readiness_check:
  path: '/api/status/ready'
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
liveness_check:
  path: '/api/status/live'
  check_interval_sec: 30
  timeout_sec: 4
  failure_threshold: 2
  success_threshold: 2
  
network:
  name: <network_name>
  subnetwork_name: <subnetowk_name>

resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 8

I am getting following error:
Step #1: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided runtime_config.jdk option 'java11' is invalid for JAR deployments. Please use a supported jdk option: ['openjdk8', 'openjdk9']
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.config.domain.JdkServerLookup.lookupJdkImage(JdkServerLookup.java:146)
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.RuntimeImageBuildStep.getBaseRuntimeImage(RuntimeImageBuildStep.java:98)
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.RuntimeImageBuildStep.run(RuntimeImageBuildStep.java:53)
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.BuildPipelineConfigurator.generateDockerResources(BuildPipelineConfigurator.java:104)
Step #1:    at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.Application.main(Application.java:147)


I intend to use openjdk11 because I see following warning
WARNING: java 8 and earlier versions will reach end of support on 2024-07-10 for App Engine flexible environment. After 2024-07-10, you cannot deploy new or re-deploy existing applications that use runtimes after their end of support date.

I am not sure what should be the value for java 11 in the runtime config. I have tried using 'jdk : java11' without any luck.

Why do you need App Engine flex? Do you have special requirements?

I am just working on an existing project which had business requirement to deploy apps to app engine flex environment. So yes, there is a requirement to deploy to app engine flex environment

As the error suggests, it may be that runtime\_config.jdk option java11 is not supported for JAR deployments in the Google App Engine Flexible environment, as it currently supports pre-built docker images for specific OpenJDK versions like openjdk8 and openjdk9 for JAR deployments.
Attached here is a documentation for reference. There are 2 approach that you can try for this concern.

You can use a supported OpenJDK version where you change the jdk value in runtime\_config to a supported version like openjdk8 or openjdk9. This ensures that the application runs on a pre-built image with the chosen OpenJDK version.

You can try to switch to Maven Buildpack as it is recommended for deploying Java applications to the Flex environment. Attaching here the documentation for deploying Maven.


